# How can I tell if sshd is running with ClientAliveInterval > 0?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm a user on a system, and I want to know if that system is running sshd with a ClientAliveInterval > 0, which would tell me if I need to worry about using ServerAliveInterval locally or not.  I can't read `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but is there a way to query sshd or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look at my question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/how-does-tcp-keepalive-work-in-ssh) This is related to yours. So the answer is: Drop the link and look if the process on the server and client side dies.

You can also watch your connection with `tcpdump -i $INTERFACE port ssh` I think it even decodes "ssh-keepalive" if it is active.

The default is "not active".

Comment: I feel like just looking for process death could be problematic, as if you won't really be able to tell the difference between sshd just dying (CAI == 0) and a small ClientAliveInterval.  However, the `tcpdump` tip worked pretty well, as of 4.1.1 it didn't seem to decode ssh-keepalive, but the regular pulse of packets every 30 seconds pretty well answered my question.

Comment: 30 seconds might be TCP-keepalive as well. I do not know if it was here or on Server Fault - but I darkly remember that tcp-keepalive is something along 30 or 60 seconds (per OS default in Linux).

Comment: I might be wrong, but the TCP-keepalive packets wouldn't have encrypted payloads?  The ones I was seeing were, so I assumed it was SSH.

Comment: Ok - then that should be clear.