# Ctrl-C handling in SSH session

Tags: ssh, signals

When I start an SSH session that executes a long-running command, what happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (SIGINT) handling?

I can see that the SSH session is closed, but I am not sure who gets the SIGINT first: is it...

1. the remote long-running command? that is, (a) the signal handler in the remote command is called and stops the remote command, (b) the shell that spawned it detects that the command stopped, and stops as well (c) the remote sshd detects the shell stopped, so it closes the connection

   or
2. the local ssh receives the signal, and closes the connection.

I think that (1) is happening, but want to make sure.

I am also uncertain about what happens with shell handling of SIGINTs in this case. For example, if I ...

```
ssh remote 'while true ; do sleep 1 ; date ; done'
```

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then the remote connection is dropped. Is there a way to run the remote command under a shell that will stay alive after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>? That is, in this case, stop the loop and allow me to keep working on the remote shell?

Comment: A noninteractive ssh (`ssh remote command`, as opposed to `ssh remote`) will be killed (on the local side) by the SIGINT generated by typing ctrl-C. The remote side will probably (depends on the OS) stay running until it tries to read or write to the closed socket. If you want all your keystrokes, including ctrl-C, to be passed on to the remote, use `ssh remote`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: OK Mark - if you add your response below as an answer, I will accept it... In my own tests, I verified that the remote doesn't receive any signal.

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40023/get-ssh-to-forward-signals

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`ssh` can be invoked in a few different ways, each resulting slightly different treatment of terminal-initiated signals like <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.

- `ssh remotehost` will run an interactive session on `remotehost`. On the client side, `ssh` will try to set the tty used by stdin to "raw" mode, and `sshd` on the remote host will allocate a pseudo-tty and run your shell as a login shell (e.g. `-bash`).

  Setting raw mode means that characters that would normally send signals (such as <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd>) are instead just inserted into the input stream. `ssh` will send such characters as-is to the remote host, where they will likely send SIGINT or SIGQUIT and, typically, kill any command and return you to a shell on the remote host. The ssh connection will stay alive, as long as the remote shell is alive.
- `ssh -t remotehost command args ...` will run an interactive session on `remotehost`, just like the above, except on the remote side, `your_shell -c "command args ..."` will be run. As above, if you type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, it will be sent to the remote host, where the command will likely receive SIGINT and immediately exit, and then the remote shell will exit. The remote `sshd` then closes the connection, and `ssh` reports `Connection to remotehost closed.`
- `ssh remotehost command args ...` will run a non-interactive session on `remotehost`. On the client side, `ssh` will *not* set the tty to raw mode (well, except to read in a password or passphrase). If you type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, `ssh` will get sent SIGINT and will immediately be terminated, without even issuing a `Connection to remotehost closed` message.

  The `your_shell -c "command args ..."` processes will *likely remain running on the remote host*. Either they will exit on their own, or one process will try to write data to the now-closed ssh socket, which will cause a (typically) fatal SIGPIPE signal to be sent to it.

Comment: Technically, the remote command doesn't write directly to the socket. Its stdout is a pipe. And sshd at the other end reads the data, encrypts it, and sends it over the socket. The end result is the same though. The command will get a sigpipe because that pipe is gone when the client disconnects.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I will edit the answer to correct it.