# How is Ctrl+c or Ctrl+z sent over SSH?

Tags: ssh, signals

I am trying to figure out exactly what is sent to an SSH host when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in either PuTTY or OpenSSH. All I am trying to do is send control codes programmatically that are equivalent to when a user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> for example. So far every time I send `^C` or `\cc` or `\003` it just prints it out. There must be some sort of additional information to let the terminal know it was `^C` escaped?

I am programmatically sending characters to an SSH session that is already connected to an SSH host. I want to see the same effect as when I have OpenSSH client open and I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on my keyboard.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to send something like CTRL-Z to an ssh session programmatically, ie from a script?

Comment: Ctrl/C and Ctrl/Z in this context are signals, not characters. You need to explain what you're trying to achieve rather than how to implement what you think needs to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send ^D / EOT character to stdin of a shell process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493578/how-to-send-d-eot-character-to-stdin-of-a-shell-process)

Comment: I am trying to send characters pragmatically to ssh clients that have an ssh session open to a host.

Comment: It all depends on *how specifically* you want to send control-C to the SSH client, and what exactly that SSH client is. The question as asked, *"what is sent to an SSH host when I press CTL-C in PuTTY"* is simple: the character control-C, `'\x03'`. OpenSSH is a suite of utilities and libraries, not an SSH client, so it's meaningless to ask what happens when you *"press CTL-C in OpenSSH"*.

Comment: Thank you @AlexP. I am open to different ways how to do this. At the moment I am looking at modifying openssh  to give me a hook write before encryption to inject bytes, or I have a mitm tool to modify packets in the tunnel if I provide the keys, but then I need to modify openssh to export them when the tunnel is formed. Open to easier ideas

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to achieve rather than how to implement what you think needs to be done. Also **show** (not explain) us what you have tried.

Comment: I am trying to mimic a keyboard in a web session where the apache web server backend, ssh's into an ubuntu desktop VM and acts exactly like if you were on the ubuntu vm directly.

Answer (score 4):

*If* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is sent over SSH, it's one byte: `^C` i.e. hex `0x03` i.e. octal `003` i.e. ASCII ETX.
*If* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is sent over SSH, it's one byte: `^Z` i.e. hex `0x1a` i.e. octal `032` i.e. ASCII SUB.

I wrote "if" because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> on the client side may or may not generate a byte that gets to the server side. And on the server side this byte may or may not get to whatever program was started by the SSH server.

I don't know how exactly PuTTY in Windows handles this, but I know the mechanics in Linux (i.e. Linux client + Linux server). My answer puts together information from several other answers:

- [How do keyboard input and text output work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116630/108618)
- [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component (software, master side, slave side)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120071/108618)
- [What’s the difference between a “raw” and a “cooked” device driver?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21760/108618)
- [Ctrl-C handling in SSH session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161878/108618)

Let's suppose you run `ssh` using a terminal emulator, then you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. This is what happens:

1. The terminal emulator generates `^C`.
2. There's a tty line discipline that may or may not intercept this byte and "convert" it to a signal.

   - If the line discipline is configured to trigger SIGINT upon `^C` then it will send SIGINT to the current foreground process group. `ssh`, being in the foreground process group, will receive the signal and exit.
   - If the line discipline is configured not to treat `^C` specially then it will send `^C` like any "normal" byte (e.g. like `a` or `5`), `ssh` will read it and send it to the remote side. And then…
3. On the remote side there may or may not be a tty allocated.

   - If there is no tty then a program started by the SSH server will receive `^C` on its stdin.
   - If there is a tty then there is a line discipline that in turn may or may not be configured to treat `^C` specially. Similarly to what can happen locally, the remote line discipline will send SIGINT to the (remote) foreground process group xor pass `^C` like any "normal" byte.

`ssh` started as `ssh … some_command` or `ssh -T …` does not allocate a tty on the remote side and does not make the local terminal stop treating `^C` specially. In effect local <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will terminate the local program (i.e. the `ssh` itself). But if you bypass the local line discipline by piping to `ssh` then you will be able to pass arbitrary data (including `^C` byte) to `some_command`; on the remote side there will be no line discipline that could mangle the data.

`ssh` started without a command or with [`-t`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t) (`-tt` is needed in some circumstances) does allocate a tty on the remote side and does make the local terminal stop treating `^C` specially. In effect local <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> won't terminate the local program (i.e. the `ssh` itself) but it will get as `^C` to the remote side where the remote line discipline will handle it; so local <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will possibly terminate the remote program. The remote line discipline won't be able to tell if `^C` it gets comes from local <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or (e.g.) from piping `printf "\003"` to `ssh`; it's the same byte. When a tty is allocated on the remote side, you cannot reliably send/receive arbitrary data by piping to/from `ssh`; the line discipline on the remote side will mangle the data. You can get some additional insight from this question of mine: [`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).

> So far every time I send `^C` or `\cc` or `\003` it just prints it out.

Possibilities:

- There is no tty on the remote side, so there is no line discipline that would "convert" `^C` to SIGINT there; and the program "prints it out" in a form you can actually see (like `cat -A`).
- Or there is a tty on the remote side, but the line discipline is configured not to treat `^C` specially; and the terminal driver xor the program "prints it out" (it's easy to configure the terminal driver to echo (in caret notation) what it gets as input: `stty ctlecho`).
- Or there is a tty on the remote side and the line discipline is configured to treat `^C` specially; but the program traps SIGINT and instead of terminating itself "prints it out".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
(echo ping google.com; sleep 3; printf "\003"; ) |
  ssh -tt localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out exactly what is sent to an SSH host when I press CTRL-C in either putty or open ssh.

i don't know.

> All I am trying to do is send control codes pragmatically that are equivalent to when a user presses CTRL-Z for example.

to send Ctrl+C programmatically, send a SIGINT to the ssh, for example:

```
killalll -s SIGINT ssh
```

will do the equivalent of pressing `ctrl+C` in all SSH sessions you have access to. likewise for Ctrl+Z use SIGTSTP:

```
killall -s SIGTSTP ssh
```

will press Ctrl+Z in all ssh terminals... and to send to just a specific ssh session, have its ssh PID and use kill

```
kill -s SIGTSTP PID
```

will send Ctrl+Z on the ssh session belonging to that PID.